# instead of removing the item from array, it is set as undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to remove the item from an `Array` using its `index`. Here is how the delete function looks like:

```
function handlePricingPlanDelete(e, index_to_remove) {
    setProductData(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        pricingplans: prevState.pricingplans.map((p, index) => {
            if (index_to_remove !== index) {
                return {
                    p
                }
            }
        })
    }))
}
```

This works fine for the most part except that instead of removing the particular item from `pricingplans` array at that position, it sets it as `undefined`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead `map`

Comment: Array::map returns an array of equal length to the source. Try array::filter instead.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array::map returns an array of equal length to the source array. The mapping with a conditional return will map an "undefined" value from the implicit void return from the callback.

Try array::filter instead to filter and return all elements that meed the condition, i.e. that aren't *that* index.

```
function handlePricingPlanDelete(e, index_to_remove) {
  setProductData(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    pricingplans: prevState.pricingplans.filter(
      (p, index) => index_to_remove !== index)
  }))
}
```